# How to get a functions's body as string?

Tags: javascript, function

I want to know how to convert a function's body into a string?

```
function A(){
  alert(1);
}

output = eval(A).toString() // this will come with  function A(){  ~ }

//output of output -> function A(){ alert(1); }

//How can I make output into alert(1); only???
```

Comment: Can I ask *why* are you doing this?

Comment: I want to customize something...

Comment: What do you want to customize? In response to what? To what effect?

Comment: sorry, I want to union 2 functions into a customize function....

Comment: @Shmiddty that will still come with function A(){ ~ }

Comment: @DavidThomas For example to convert function to base64 data in order to run it within web worker. It's much better than just putting bas64 crap in your code...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you're going to do something ugly, do it with regex:

```
A.toString().match(/function[^{]+\{([\s\S]*)\}$/)[1];
```

Comment: thank you very much!!! can I also ask do you have any reference sites are giving good teaching about how to use regex??

Comment: I don't agree with what the OP's doing, but I do agree that: 'if you're going to do something ugly (you might as well) do it with regex.' =D

Comment: yes, I understand this is ugly.. but still depends on what are you building....the function in js is value only, it means string..

Comment: "If you're going to do something ugly, do it with regex:" Quote of the Week!

Comment: This does not work for functions defined like `() => {}`.  Run this code for an example `(() => {console.log(1);}).toString().match(/function[^{]+\{([\s\S]*)\}$/)[1];`

Comment: Funny enough, if you do `function a(b = {}) { // c }` it will match `}) { // c`. Therefor, this post is not really useful.

Comment: @Mr.DeleteMyMessages: Please check the date, I wrote this before this syntax was valid. You may need alternate regex to match default arg values, destructuring, arrow funcs, and other new features. But if you’re doing that you may be using a transpiler, in which case this approach is probably a Bad Idea to begin with (because your transpiled code may have different source from what you expect).

Answer (score 8):

Don't use a regexp.

```js
const getBody = (string) => string.substring(
  string.indexOf("{") + 1,
  string.lastIndexOf("}")
)

const f = () => { return 'yo' }
const g = function (some, params) { return 'hi' }
const h = () => "boom"

console.log(getBody(f.toString()))
console.log(getBody(g.toString()))
console.log(getBody(h.toString())) // fail !
```

Comment: won't work if my function bears an argument with such default value: `function fn(a = {}) { return "hello"; }`

Answer (score 2):

You could just stringify the function and extract the body by removing everything else:

```
A.toString().replace(/^function\s*\S+\s*\([^)]*\)\s*\{|\}$/g, "");
```

However, there is no good reason to do that and [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) actually doesn't work in all environments.

Comment: Or more concisely:

     f.toString().replace(/(^.*?\{|\}$)/g, "")

Comment: This does not work for functions defined like `() => {}`.  Run this code for an example `(() => {console.log(1);}).toString().replace(/^function\s*\S+\s*\([^)]*\)\s*\{|\}$/g, "");`

Comment: @MattClimbs Of course it doesn't, the answer is from 2013 :-) It also doesn't work on concise methods, generators, async functions… If you want to recognise an ES6 function with default parameter initialisers, you need a proper parser - regex is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

#### This coud be what youre looking for

```js
const toString = (func) => `(${func.toString()})()`
    
console.log(toString(() => {
    console.log("Hello world")
}))
```

This will execute the function.

Comment: OP asked to stringify the function body, this gives the function itself as a string

Answer (score 0):

Currently, developers are using **arrow functions** with the new releases of Ecmascript.

Hence, I would like to share [the answer here which is the answer of Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38466463/747579)

```js
    function getArrowFunctionBody(f) {
      const matches = f.toString().match(/^(?:\s*\(?(?:\s*\w*\s*,?\s*)*\)?\s*?=>\s*){?([\s\S]*)}?$/);
      if (!matches) {
        return null;
      }
      
      const firstPass = matches[1];
      
      // Needed because the RegExp doesn't handle the last '}'.
      const secondPass =
        (firstPass.match(/{/g) || []).length === (firstPass.match(/}/g) || []).length - 1 ?
          firstPass.slice(0, firstPass.lastIndexOf('}')) :
          firstPass
      
      return secondPass;
    }
    
    const K = (x) => (y) => x;
    const I = (x) => (x);
    const V = (x) => (y) => (z) => z(x)(y);
    const f = (a, b) => {
      const c = a + b;
      return c;
    };
    const empty = () => { return undefined; };
    console.log(getArrowFunctionBody(K));
    console.log(getArrowFunctionBody(I));
    console.log(getArrowFunctionBody(V));
    console.log(getArrowFunctionBody(f));
    console.log(getArrowFunctionBody(empty));
```

**Original [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453881/how-to-get-an-arrow-functions-body-as-a-string)**

Comment: In my case I used: `^(?:\s*function)?.*\(.*\)(?:\s*=>)?\s*\{[ \t]*\r?\n?([^]*)(?=\})` which doesn't need special cases for `}` as it uses lookahead group.