# Turn script content of a function into string

Tags: javascript

For example, if i have something like this:

```
function hello() {console.log("hello")}
```

I want to be able to make a function in java script that would return a string value:

```
"console.log("hello");"
```

Is there a way to do this with plain javascript?

Comment: What would you need that for?

Comment: Sometimes `toString` is overridden, which is why it's better to use `Function.prototype.toString.call(hello);`. However, there is almost no use-case where this is a good solution and very likely there is a much better solution to your actual problem if you let us know more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all of the code including the function declaration by calling the `toString()` method on the function. You can then parse this string to remove the unwanted information.

Something like this:

```
function hello() {
    console.log("hello");
}

var f = hello.toString();//get string of whole function
f = f.substring(f.indexOf('{') + 1);//remove declaration and opening bracket
f = f.substring(0, f.length - 1);//remove closing bracket
f = f.trim();//remove extra starting/eding whitespace

console.log(f);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ULygF/)

Answer (score 1):

If you do `hello.toString()` it will output `"function hello() {console.log("hello")}"`

Comment: but see [the question yours duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885995/how-to-get-a-functionss-body-as-string) for the complete answer

Answer (score 0):

The others has already provided the right answer if you base directly from the function created, but if you want to create a literal string instead. Just quote it properly:

```
function hello() { return "console.log(\"hello\")"; };
```

This should show `console.log("hello")` on the page anyhow.

```
<html><head></head><body><script>
    function hello() { return "console.log(\"hello\")"; };
    document.write(hello());
</script><body></html>
```

Comment: it would not be a string though