# Does Arrow function has delegate attribute like Groovy Closure

Tags: javascript, groovy, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

Using groovy , you can run **closure**  like following :

```
  instanceB.methodB({
          methodA(3);
          methodA(3);
  }); 
  //---- methodB definition 
  class B{
       def methodB(Closure c){
             c.delegate=new A(); //!!!---The question is about this "delegate" in JS
             c.call();
       }

  }
```

As you may note, we call directly `methodA` inside closure without `this` (`this.methodA()`) .
This is because of this instruction `c.delegate=new A()` : Therefore, All methods of `new A()` can be called there .

## My question :

How to make this works with Javascript using Arrow-functions : Either ES6 or ES7 .

Does Arrow-functions has something like `delegate` ?

## Pseudo code :

```
instanceB.methodB(()=>{
     methodA(3); 
     methodA(4);
});
class B{
     methodB(arrow){
         arrow.delegate=new A(); // What's the right way, if any ?
         arrow.call();  
     }

}
```

Comment: Any update? no one know both Groovy&JS

Comment: I have no idea what this has to do with arrow functions. There is no special scoping for them in JS.

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/21562973/1048572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, arrow functions do not have such a feature and neither have any other functions.

Scope is lexically determined in JS, i.e. it depends on where you declare your functions, and you cannot inject anything or modify it from outside.

Your best bet might be the [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), although you have to put it inside your (arrow) function not at the call site, or `eval`.