# How Do i change a url in a javascript file using javascript Automation Testing

Tags: javascript, automation, stubbing

I am trying to modify a URL within a javascript file in my automation tests. This is so I can point off to a stubbed version of a service. The framework i am using for testing is Serenity-js (Using protractor)

In my HTML DOM I have:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>`

main.js

```
var DataService = (function () {
    function DataService(http) {
        this.http = http;
    }
    DataService.prototype.getStudentDetails = function (id) {
        var parcel = this.http
            .get('http://127.0.0.1/endpoint/' + id)
            .map(function (res) {
            return __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__student_model__["a"].createStudent(res.json());
        });
        return student;
    };
    return DataService;
}());
```

The part i need to change is `127.0.0.1/endpoint`

I know I cold change the HTML DOM using `$.document.write` or `$().append` but don't know how to change/overwirte a DOM element.

Comment: You could use a JS variable, or an 'input hidden' field.

Comment: the main.js file is an existing production system. I would rather not change the source code where it may open vulnerablities from other users. I would rather try and change 'on the fly' as it were.

Comment: Ah! That's where you're comin from! I'm sorry I completely misunderstood.

Comment: Also, only way I can think of is to call `var functionString =  DataService.getStudentDetails(id).toString()`. Then you could alter the string and do `new Function(functionString)`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885995/how-to-get-a-functionss-body-as-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple, but there are so many ways of doing it!

1. As part of the setup phase before running your tests, you could just pre-process the `main.js` file using a `sed` or `awk` script and replace all occurrences of the `127...` string with something else.
2. Change the code in the production system to read from a configuration variable containing all the url endpoints. You could then just change that object in your test script.
3. Use your test script to replace the function with something else. This is what @alok suggests in the comments, but the comment was missing `prototype`, and the method should also not have been invoked, so the code  should look something like this:

Example of #3:

```
 const newFnString = DataService.prototype.getStudentDetails.toString()
                         .replace("127.0.0.1", "something.com");
 DataService.prototype.getStudentDetails = new Function(newFnString);
```

Of course, you could just have replaced `DataService.prototype.getStudentDetails` with any given function, as you have total control over it (unless it is hidden in a closure).

P.S. Trying to secure your systems by making it harder to tamper with the javascript is just security through obscurity - it's not real. Any attacker can just read the network requests anyhow, and replay them in `curl` or Postman.

Comment: @AndrewEvans Great to hear. Which of the three approaches did you go for?