# Call callback from created <script> in created <iframe>

Tags: javascript

I have a js code which should create a new *iframe*, then create a new *script* with a code and insert the created *script* into created *iframe*.

Everything works fine except *callback* which is defined in main's page js and which I should call from the inserted *script*, because it isn't defined in the created *script*.

My code looks like:

```js
(function(){
    function makeIframe(adElement, callback){
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.appendChild(createScriptTag());

        adElement.appendChild(iframe);
        adElement.parentNode.insertBefore(iframe, adElement);

        function createScriptTag(){
            var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
            scriptTag.innerHTML = getFunctionBodyAsString(innerCode);
            return scriptTag;
        }

        function innerCode(){
            callback();
        }

        function getFunctionBodyAsString(fun){
            return fun.toString().match(/function[^{]+\{([\s\S]*)\}$/)[1];
        }
    }

    makeIframe(document.getElementById('sth-id'), function(){
        alert("Works!")
    });

}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="sth-id"></div>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

My question is, how can I call *callback* function from the creted *script* in the created *iframe*?

PS. I'm not very experienced with js, any suggestion to present code will be hopefull :)

**Update 1:**

The only place where I can define my *callback* function it's in the js *script* (test.js) and also from this place I should call function (in example *makeIframe*) which runs all other logic.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe

Comment: Are you sure the top frame and the `<iframe>` are same domain?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts no it doesn't and it shouldn't

Comment: @CBroe I can't figure out, how can I call my *callback* function from *iframe* by using this.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ the same question as for CBroe?

Comment: You are not calling the `callback` function anywhere so far ... instead, there is a weird construct that seems to try and mess with the actual function source code - what is that supposed to be good for?

Comment: @CBroe I'm creating *iframe* and inject there js *script* which should make request and do some logic in *iframe* on success or call user's function (*callback*) on fail. I looked everythere for this problem, I'm new in JS, I know the code which I wrote is not the best so I suppose someone helps me with this problem and also give tips for code in my question (Mayby there are others solutions). The main problem is that I have no access to page, a page's owner just put there my js script (only one file).

Comment: Well right now the _only_ thing you insert to the script element inside the iframe seems to be the code of the callback function ... where’s the rest of it? That whole innerCode/ getFunctionBodyAsString stuff smells rather nonsense-y to me.

Comment: 1. I have the problem just with *callback* so I don't provide other logic (to not bore people with unneeded code for this example), because the rest works fine (I just can not inject *callback* function). 

2. "getFunctionBodyAsString stuff smells rather nonsense-y to me" I don't like this solution too, but I couldn't find anything better, if you have better idea on how inject js script from one js script section to another script section I'll be glad to see it :) I use it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885995/how-to-get-a-functionss-body-as-string

Comment: Any reasons for downvoting are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

since you want to avoid loading an external script, You can include the JS code you want inside your HTML markup and retrieve it using the DOM API.

```js
(function() {
  function makeIframe(adElement, callback) {
    var script = document.querySelector('#adscript');
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    script.type = "text/javascript"
    iframe.appendChild(script);

    adElement.appendChild(iframe);
    adElement.parentNode.insertBefore(iframe, adElement);
  }

}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="sth-id"></div>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  <script type="text" id="adScript">
    //doWhatever alert('it works')
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I need it for advertising purpose, so it should be as fast as possible. By "scriptTag.src = linkToExternalJS;" I make additional request which is time waste for me :(

Comment: @AndrewChmielowski , I updated my  answer to avoid making another network request.. asides from this, all you can do is include your js code as an inline script

Comment: I've updated my question, I can't modify the web page by pre-adding additional html tag. I can add tags only by my js *script*.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want to achieve with the callbak, but the problem is that the `callback` you are calling inside the `innerCode` function isn't defined anywhere in the code..
It seems to me now, like you are trying to solve two problems:
 1. how to insert script into an iframe
 2. how to send message from iframe to parent window;

for 1. I think both my previous answers address the issue and for 2.
 as others have pointed out, the easiest way for passing in information between windows is using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: I added in the question's comments, I can't modify html, a owner of a page provide me just with one <div id="known-id"> and <script src="to my code"> and it's all I can't modify page's DOM (I can just add elements to provided <div>) also I can't make any of my js's variable global-visible (it's why I put my code in self-executed function). By using your solutions I shoud eaither modify DOM (out of the <div>) or make at least one variable global-visible. ps. I should load addition <script> it's the reason why I use iframe and put there my code.